# Supermarket jargon

Tags: word-choice

Imagine you’re at the supermarket and there is a long line at the checkout counter and there is only one cashier although there are two counters. The cashier at the counter calls for help over the P A system. What would you expect to hear?

1. Would a colleague please staff counter 2?
2. Would a colleague please make themselves available at counter 2?
3. Please occupy counter 2.
4. Something else?

Thank you.

Comment: This is entirely up to the store's established procedures.  Sometimes it's "More checkers needed", sometimes it's "Fred, could you take register 6?", sometimes it's "DQ-7".

Comment: "Cashier needed for counter 2." Simple and clear, easy to understand over a public address system in a noisy store.